# Cannot populate fields inside a handlebar if statement

Tags: javascript, meteor, modal-dialog

I have a modal box with some fields in there, and based on some values in other fields, they may or may not appear.

So the fields look like

```
<div class="row">
  <select class="form-control" id="ddlNewInputType" placeholder="Enter your input type">
    <option value="input">Input</option>
    <option value="formula">Formula</option>
  </select>
</div>


{{#if isFormula }}
  <div class="row">
    <input type="text" id="txtNewInputFormula" placeholder="Enter formula">
  </div>
{{/if}}
```

There is a helper that determines whether the txtNewInputFormula textbox is shown

```
isFormula: ->
  return Template.instance().isFormula.get();
```

isFormula is a ReactiveVar that gets populated when the dropdown list changes

```
'change #ddlNewInputType': (e,t) ->
  isFormula = $(e.currentTarget).val() == 'formula'
  t.isFormula.set(isFormula);
```

In effect, the rule is if the input type = input, don't display the formula field, and if the input type = formula, display the formula field.

When my modal box loads up, it is either for a new or existing object. If it is an existing object, I prepopulate the modal box with values in the database like this

```
'click #btnEditInput': ->
    $('#addInputModal').modal()
    $('#txtNewInputName').val(this.name)
    $('#txtNewInputFormula').val(this.formula)
    $('#ddlNewInputType').val(this.inputType)
    $('#ddlNewInputType').change()
```

The problem is every field except for txtNewInputFormula is being populated. I suspect txtNewInputFormula is not populated because it is inside the handlebar if statement and that hasn't been evaluated yet and therefore, the HTML element does not exist.

How can I get around this? How can I populate a HTML element inside an IF statement?

Answer (score 4):

You're probably correct in your diagnostic, have you tried using handlebars syntax to reactively populate the input text value with appropriate data ?

Something like this :

```
{{#if isFormula }}
  <div class="row">
    <input type="text" id="txtNewInputFormula" placeholder="Enter formula" value="{{formula}}">
  </div>
{{/if}}
```

Making the input value into a reactive helper will set it regardless when the DOM element is ultimately created.

Generally speaking, when you find yourself manipulating jQuery to modify the DOM and bypassing Blaze, you may get into trouble.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @saimeunt, you shouldn't be manipulating the DOM with jQuery like this. You should look at having a wrapper for adding modal templates to the DOM, and providing data.

However, if you wanted to just make your code work, you can.

Basically you want to delay the update to `#txtNewInputFormula` until after the next flush.

```
'click #btnEditInput': ->
    formula = this.formula
    Tracker.afterFlush ->
      $('#txtNewInputFormula').val(formula)
      return
    $('#txtNewInputName').val(name)
    $('#ddlNewInputType').val(this.inputType).change()
    $('#addInputModal').modal()
    return
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is using [autoform](https://atmospherejs.com/aldeed/autoform) package.

In the schema you can define a field is depending on another field. Then when you call 
`{{#autoform collection=...}}{{afInputField...}}...{{/autoform}}`, it will show or hide the respective filed.

An example can be found [here](http://autoform.meteor.com/fieldvalues) with 2 fields A and B: B will show if A is selected:

Schemas:

```
FieldValueIs = new Mongo.Collection("FieldValueIs");
FieldValueIs.attachSchema(new SimpleSchema({
  a: {
    type: String,
    allowedValues: ["foo", "bar"]
  },
  b: {
    type: String
  }
}));
```

HTML form:

```
{{#autoForm collection="FieldValueIs" type="insert" id="FieldValueIsForm"}}
  {{> afQuickField name="a" options="allowed" noselect=true}}
  {{#if afFieldValueIs name="a" value="foo"}}
    {{> afQuickField name="b"}}
  {{/if}}
{{/autoForm}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into putting the content of the if statement into its own template and populating it using the [rendered](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_rendered) function of a Template?  I am assuming this is meteor because of your tag.

This is only partial code of course, but something like:

html:

```
<template name="someTemplate">
  //....
  <div class="row">
    <select class="form-control" id="ddlNewInputType" placeholder="Enter your input type">
      <option value="input">Input</option>
      <option value="formula">Formula</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  {{#if isFormula }}
    {{>formulaInput}}
  {{/if}}
  //....
</template>


<template name="formulaInput">
  <div class="row">
    <input type="text" id="txtNewInputFormula" placeholder="Enter formula">
  </div>
</template>
```

js:

```
Template.formulaInput.rendered = function(){
    //do the populating
}
```

The rendered function is called when the function is rendered which in this case would be when the `isFormula` helper function is returning true. The meteor [manual](http://manual.meteor.com/#blaze-howtemplatesuseblaze) have some great information on how Blaze/Template works.